# Flutter enums i18n

Tags: flutter, enums, internationalization, translation

I have a simple enum:

```
enum { TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_C ...}
```

My use case is to iterate over the enum values and print out translation of it.

Is there a way to do this with the standard i18n from Flutter?

Otherwise can someone recommend a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [slang](https://pub.dev/packages/slang):

```dart
enum MyEnum {
  TYPE_A,
  TYPE_B,
  TYPE_C;

String get label {
  switch (this) {
    case MyEnum.TYPE_A: return t.myEnum.typeA;
    case MyEnum.TYPE_B: return t.myEnum.typeB;
    case MyEnum.TYPE_C: return t.myEnum.typeC;
  }
}
```

The JSON would look like this:

```json
{
  "myEnum": {
    "typeA": "A",
    "typeB": "B",
    "typeC": "C"
  }
}
```